# Find position of minimum value in a table range excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in excel file, please have a look on below image:-

[image]

I want to know the position of cell which has minimum value.

As you can see cell AE26 has the minimum value.

I am trying below formula :-

```
=CELL("ADDRESS",INDEX(Z7:AJ26,MATCH(MIN(Z7:AJ26),Z7:AJ26,0)))
```

But it is giving "#N/A" :- "A value is not available to the formula and function."

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Match() on a multi-column range.

Your scenario can work if you use a helper column and a helper row to identify which row and which column holds the smallest value of the table.

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The conditionally formatted table has the defined name `MyTable`.

Cell D1 calculates the minimum value in the table with the formula

```
=MIN(MyTable)
```

D1 has the range name `SmallNumber`.

Cell I3 has the following formula, copied down

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(SmallNumber,B3:H3,0)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Cell B15 has the following formula, copied across:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(SmallNumber,B3:B14,0)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

The intersection of the "TRUE" values is the location of the smallest number in the table. If you want to return the cell address of that, you can use the formula in cell D2

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(MyTable,MATCH(TRUE(),I3:I14,0),MATCH(TRUE(),B15:H15,0)))
```

You can see a sample file [here](http://1drv.ms/1NTApjl).